# Appengine custom domain sometimes redirecting to google.com

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http, gwt, dns

I have an appengine application written in Java with a GWT frontend.

I have my own DNS configured, through "domains" in the google admin console, to point to my appengine application. This configuration have been working very well for about three years.

Starting three weeks ago, me and some testing users started to witness sporadic redirections (302) to google.com when typing our domain. Nothing related to that requests appears on appengine log, so, I'm assuming that it's not a problem related with the project or its configuration in appengine. Also, nothing was changed in my domains (google admin) configuration and DNS recently.

What is strange, is that this problem occurs about one time per day (sometimes more) and it lasts some minutes. It doesn't occur at the same time for everyone and, when the problem occurs, opening in another browser or smartphone everything works fine. After some minutes everything starts to work normally in that browser.

Anyone have any clue on what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

Please see [Google Cloud Status](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/15012) dashboard for additional information on a recent issue with custom domains.

I am not positive whether previous problem occurrences for your domain were caused by the same problem, though.

Comment: Probably was that recent issue that scared me and motivated me to ask the question. But my problem are happening for some weeks.

Comment: @HugoPinto have you mapped a naked domain (domain.com) to your application or created a CNAME (www.domain.com)?